# Node.JS Express Server not working from Enide

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodeclipse, enide

I have a webserver written in Node.JS using express, using a bunch of route commands. Everything is working fine, when running Node from the command line, but when running from within the Enide environment, for every request, I get an error message saying that an Illegal Json is received and the body is empty. This is before the route function is actually called, so I could not even examine the request header. I've removed the express logic and declared a basic http server that simply prints the request header. The body field was missing from this header. Has anyone run into a similar problem with the Enide environment?

Comment: Have you checked if node version you have in your terminal is the same enide uses?

Comment: I haven't compared the Node versions, but whatever default command line version of Node is installed on Mac/Linux/Windows is working with my code, so I'd be surprised if there was something unique to the Node that Enide is using.

Answer (score 0):

You were likely use some environment variable that were were configured/passed with Enide,
and for that you should have showed some code.

Otherwise it is just guessing.